# Can't get access to registry key

Tags: c++, c, sql-server, windows

I want to get access to the register key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL

I can see it in the regedit.exe (I copied above path from there).

But code:

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD err = RegOpenKeyExW( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Instance Names\\SQL", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey );
```

returns an error 2 (0x2): The system cannot find the file specified .

Comment: Is your program 32bit or 64bit?  If 32bit it will be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @ Richard Critten. What you mean about program? Operating System or program that executes code to find register key? OS - 64bit, Application - 32bit

Comment: Does your key include the `name` field too? I don't have your key, but when I try `L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\DirectX"` the success value `0` is returned. However when I include a field name like `L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\DirectX\\Version"` the error value `2` is returned.

Comment: @kaa it's using the `Wow6432Node` node as it is running in the 32bit emulation subsystem.  You will probably need a 64 bit application.  32bit apps on 64 bit Windows only see an emulated view of the registry. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Richard Critten . thanks for the hint, I will dig in this direction. I builded the app for the 64 arch. but this did not help at this moment.

Comment: @RichardCritten is almost right. In a 32-bit application just set `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` in the `samDesired` parameter to access `HKLM\SOFTWARE` instead of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`.

Comment: @eryksun flag KEY_WOW64_64KEY works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32-bit application running under a 64 - bit system, the registry may be redirected.
I don't know whether related to this?
Can be added when the first RegOpen KEY_WOW64_64KEY parameters.
Or use RegDisableReflectionKey disable redirection.